# Grunt specify order of injected files in index.html

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, angular-fullstack

I am using a angular-fullstack yeoman generator for one of my projects and if I run grunt build my index.html is overwritten with the injected dependencies that grunt-injector finds. The problem is that I want to specify the loading of some of the modules in a certain order or I just want to ignore a specific folder. How can I do that? Currently some javaScript files are loaded in a wrong order and every time I run grunt build I get an error.

Answer (score 4):

you can use arrays to specify the order, for instance

```js
// Inject application script files into index.html
scriptsVendor: {
    options: {
      transform: function(filePath) {
        filePath = filePath.replace('/app/', '');
        return '<script src="' + filePath + '"></script>';
      },
      starttag: '<!-- injector:js -->',
      endtag: '<!-- endinjector -->'
    },
    files: {
      'app/index.html': [
        [
          'app/lib/js/jquery.js',
          'app/lib/js/bootstrap.js',
          'app/lib/js/angular.js'
        ],
        [
          'app/lib/js/angular-*.js',
          'app/lib/js/ui-*.js'
        ]
      }
    }
```

So I load before `jquery` then `bootstrap`, `angular`. In the next block all the angular modules starting with `angular-` and `ui-`.

To ignore certain files or folder

```
!app/lib/js/*.min.js
!app/lib/js/folder_to_ignore/*.js
```

Even if a bit late I hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

in my case I have several angular modules, with config and run functions, seperated over three files called xyz.module.js, xyz.config.js, xyz.run.js

Gulp searches for all .js files : "**/*.js" and alphabetical order is used when injecting, hence *.module.js is loaded after *.config.js, which delivers errors about lacking xyz module definition.

So the order should be switched. I don't want to use hardcoded arrays, I want to keep using wildcards.

Solution which does it in my case :
[https://ww](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-filesort)

usage (in gulpfile) :

```
var angularFilesort = require('gulp-angular-filesort');
gulp.src(['./src/app/**/*.js']).pipe(angularFilesort())
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to tag on to @felix-at-housecat's answer, I needed to ensure that `angular-translate-handler-log.js` was rendered after `angular-translate.js`, but due to alphabetical sorting, it would show up before. To achieve this, I set up the injector as follows:

```
injector: {
    dev: {
        files: {
            'dist/static/index.html': [
                [
                    'dist/static/js/lib/jquery.js',
                    'dist/static/js/lib/bootstrap.js',
                    'dist/static/js/lib/angular.js',
                    'dist/static/js/lib/angular-*.js',
                    'dist/static/js/lib/angularjs*.js',
                    . . .
                     '!dist/static/js/lib/angular-translate-handler-log.js'
                ],
                [
                    'dist/static/js/lib/angular-translate-handler-log.js'
                ]
            ]
        },
. . .
```

Now,  `/angular-translate-handler-log.js` will be rendered in the file after all of the files in the first array (which includes `angular-translate.js`).